# How to obfuscate an Unity plugin project code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, dll, plugins, obfuscation

I have an Unity plugin project which is basically a set of files (.cs), functions and libraries that anyone can use in their projects, is there any way to obfuscate all the code in this project so that people using it can only see the headers of the functions, prefabs, resources..., and not the content of the code? I would like not to have to redo a lot of code and know if there is some simple way that, given an Unity project, obfuscates its scripts, or ultimately put all the scripts together in one or more dll but still work in the same way (components can be added to gameobjects, the functions of the top bar of the Unity editor are still maintained, prefabs don't break...)

Comment: Did you already find any obfuscator software on the web? for ex. https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/obfuscator-48919 seems like there should be something out there for this kinda thing does it not?

Comment: @sommmen Yes, but most of them are paid and if they are not, they only obfuscate C# code, which would complicate the fact of integrating it well into Unity. What I want to achieve is the same as some plugins from the Unity asset store that you can create components or call functions from it but you cannot read their code (like Unity metadata code on some UnityEngine classes like MonoBehaviour)

Comment: Those 'Unity metadata code on some UnityEngine classes like MonoBehaviour' is because unityengine is not written in csharp. It has nothing to do with obfuscation AFAIK.  but yes those are the tradeoffs of obfuscating. But the one i linked has some options to skip fields and so on which would be in your direction. Perhaps if you've seen this from plugins like you mention you could ask some authors what they use?

Comment: If you e.g. use Jetbrains Rider with/or [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) you can actually look into all Unity c# classes down to the level where the native stuff is called (basically what they provide anyway in the [source code](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference) but also for types not in there ;) ) and even there you can dig deeper via the decompiled IL code ;)

Comment: @derHugo So what is the currently safest way to avoid being able to read unity c# code? Is this option good https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/obfuscator-48919 ?